# Is it possible with Fixture to create a list of N objects?

Tags: c#, fixture

I want to create with Fixture a list of N objects.

I know I can do it with:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPersons; i++)
{
    Person person = fixture.Build<Person>().Create();
    persons.Add(person);
}
```

Is there any way I can use the `CreateMany()` method or some other method in order to avoid the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it people.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a class containing extension methods for AutoFixture.
/// </summary>
public static class AutoFixtureExtensions
{
    #region Extension Methods For IPostprocessComposer<T>

    public static IEnumerable<T> CreateSome<T>(this IPostprocessComposer<T> composer, int numberOfObjects)
    {
        if (numberOfObjects < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The number of objects is negative!");
        }

        IList<T> collection = new List<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            collection.Add(composer.Create<T>());
        }

        return collection;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Found the answer. CreateMany has some overloads that get 'count'.

Thanks people.

Comment: how did you find the answer just within 100 seconds since you posted the question !! :P

Comment: When 'count' is zero it does not return an empty collection but it throws an expception. Bad implementation.

Answer (score 6):

you can use linq:

```
  List<Person> persons = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfPersons)
            .Select(x => fixture.Build<Person>().Create())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I will accept it for now. But, I would like a solution with a more Fixture way rather than LINQ.

Comment: Not working. It shows a warning that Select has two overloaded methods.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution by using only Fixture?

Comment: Nowaday at least you can also, in a one liner, adapt any property using linq:
List<Person> persons = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfPersons)
            .Select(x => fixture.Build<Person>()
            .With(p => p.Name, "Some name")
            .With(p => p.Address, "Some address").Create())
            .ToList();

Answer (score 6):

Yes Sure, you can use the `CreateMany` as the next sample:

```
var numberOfPersons = 10; //Or your loop length number
var fixture = new Fixture();
var person = fixture.CreateMany<Person>(numberOfPersons).ToList(); 
//ToList() to change  the IEnumerable to List
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dtos = (new Fixture()).CreateMany<YourObjectType>(numberRecords);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var people = _fixture
        .Build<Person>()
        .CreateMany()
        .ToList(); // if you want to return a generic list
```

Comment: Hey Enes, could you maybe elaborate a bit on the answer?

Comment: hi sorry for the late response. You can send an integer value to the `CreateMany()` function. it would return you that amount of instance you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoFixture.CreateMany(n) where n is the numbers of items you want :

```
var persons = Fixture.CreateMany<Person>(100).ToList();
//persons.Count() = 100
```

You can also configure AutoFixture with pre-configured numbers of items with [RepeatCount](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/11/AnonymousSequencesWithAutoFixture/) :

```
fixture.RepeatCount = 100;
var persons = fixture.CreateMany<Person>().ToList();
//persons.Count() = 100
```